# Send a PHP variable value through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using AJAX to get the amount of players that are online on a server. I call the ajax function on my main page using this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("avatarquery.php", function(players) {
            $("#playersPLZ").text(players);
        });
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

On the page avatarquery.php I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once 'checkinfo.php';
echo getPlayersTotal();
?>
```

Lastly, I use the following code on the checkinfo.php page to ping the server and send the data back to the previous pages:

```
<?php

function getPlayersTotal() {
$version = 0;
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//ini_set("track_errors", 1);
//ini_set("html_errors", 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);


$SERVER_IP = "37.187.139.123"; 
$SERVER_PORT = "26618"; 
$QUERY_PORT = "26618";

$HEADS = "3D"; 
$show_max = "unlimited"; 
$SHOW_FAVICON = "on"; 

$TITLE = "My fancy Serverpage";
$TITLE_BLOCK_ONE = "General Information";
$TITLE_BLOCK_TWO = "Players";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/ping/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $SERVER_PORT . ''), true);
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/query/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $QUERY_PORT . ''), true);


if(empty($ping['error'])) { 
$version = $ping['version']['name'];
$online = $ping['players']['online'];
$max = $ping['players']['max'];
$motd = $ping['description'];
$favicon = $ping['favicon'];
}

if(empty($query['error'])) {
$playerlist = $query['Playerlist'];
}

return $version;
}
echo getPlayersTotal();
?>
```

Currently the $SERVER_IP and $SERVER_PORT variables are defined directly in the checkinfo.php code.
However, I would like to send the value for these variables from my main page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them as parameters to your function, e.g.

```
function getPlayersTotal($ip, $port) { ... }
echo getPlayersTotal($_REQUEST['ipcheck'], ...);
```

or just move the variable definitions in your main file:

```
$SERVER_IP = $_REQUEST['ipcheck']; 
$SERVER_PORT = $_REQUEST['portcheck']; 
require_once 'checkinfo.php';
```